# Apache Camel disconnect from route in case of error and continue routing

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a RouteBuilder that's managed at runtime. I want to disconnect my client from a route when it throws an error without sending a response to the client. I also need to keep it routing trough the whole process. What can I do to disconnect the client without stop my route? Any help will be appreciated.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(true)
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Log.error(String.format(Constants.ERROR_ROUTING_TO, endPointFrom.toUrl(), endPointTo.toUrl(), 
                exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class)));
            //TODO I WANT TO DISCONNECT FROM ROUTE HERE
        }

    });

    from(endPointFrom.toUrl())
    .routeId(endPointFrom.getId())
    .description(endPointFrom.toString())
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {


        }
    })
    .to(endPointTo.toUrl());

}
```

Comment: Depends what component/client you are using, and whether that is possible. You don't tell very much about what are in use.

Comment: I forgot about this, I use the jetty component

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by setting null on response body of exchange variable and so Apache Camel disconnects the client without sending the response message.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(true)
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Log.error(String.format(Constants.ERROR_ROUTING_TO, endPointFrom.toUrl(), endPointTo.toUrl(), 
                exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class)));
                exchange.getOut().setBody(null);
        }

    });

    from(endPointFrom.toUrl())
    .routeId(endPointFrom.getId())
    .description(endPointFrom.toString())
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        }

    })
    .to(endPointTo.toUrl());

}
```